# Empty clipboard after reading rich text from a file in autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey, clipboard

I'm trying to make read-write a rich text of clipboard from-to file ([source](http://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47867-new-line-in-msgbox/?p=298653), [official](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm)). After reading, paste in a wysiwyg editor in a browser (in confluence).

Looks quite simple, but in fact it **does not work** when I'm trying to paste a saved content.

So, this code does nothing:

```
FileRead, Clipboard, *c %A_ScriptDir%\Content.clip
Sleep, 100
Send, ^v
```

**UPD**

Found out a way.
Here is [a simple working example](https://gist.github.com/andkirby/446f060f61c74e07585c9fd7cc68e9f5.js).

Comment: I don't think you really explained clearly what's supposed to happen, and what happens instead? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @0x464e, Yeah, I missed to add "not". My bad. Thx for your comment. I'm not getting content from the file with saved clipboard. That's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the [`*c`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileRead.htm#Parameters) option.
Keep it mind that the option has to precede your file.
`FileRead, Clipboard, *c %A_ScriptDir%\Content.clip`

Also, use [`ClipWait`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ClipWait.htm) instead of sleep.

Comment: No, I have it. Sorry, I was typing it manually and forgot to add it.

Comment: Just wrote a simple script it's working... May the deal in `ClipWait`, idk. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Here is my simple example: https://gist.github.com/andkirby/446f060f61c74e07585c9fd7cc68e9f5.js

Comment: Yep, it works fine. Thanks. Perhaps, I did some mistakes in the code. I'm trying to make a form for pasting saved content which will be accessible by a button. Can share a complete file if you want to.

Comment: Good to hear. And no need to share it, unless you maybe want to receive some possible code cleaning/improvement suggestions.